# Форматированый ввод в андроид

Tags: android, java

Необходимо организовать проверку ввода в текстовое поле по фильтру.

> `+Х(ХХХ) ХХХ-ХХХХ`

Идеальный сценарий таков. Изначально текст ввода выглядит так:

> `+_ ( _ _ _   )    _ _ _-_ _ _ _ .`

Пользователь вводит только цифры и они встают на свои места. Т.е. после первой цифры будет так:

> `+7 ( _ _ _   )    _ _ _-_ _ _ _`

Второй:

> `+7 (4 _ _ )    _ _ _-_ _ _ _` и т.п.

Помогите с реализацией, примеры идеи...  Сам нашел это: [using a mask with EditText](http://horribile.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-mask-with-edittext.html), но до ума довести не получается.

```
package my.dfedorenko;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TestPhoneparserActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EditText phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);  
    phone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher("(###) ###-##-##"));  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое простое, что приходит в голову, - нарезать текст *.substring()*, дальше надо смотреть, как у тебя вообще реализован ввод, через какие виджеты? Или просто в строку...

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TestPhoneparserActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    EditText phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);  
    phone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher("(###) ###-##-##"));

}}
```

Comment: в обычный текст филд.

Comment: ну пока что нечего красивого не придумал, кроме - просто менять _ на цифру по индексу позиции

Comment: кстати, насчет того поста, что ты нашел - там все просто, только копи-паст и указываешь, маску под которую хочешь подогнать результат.

Comment: при попытке запустить то что я нашел приложение вылетает, причину ищу.

Comment: а логи что говорят?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jSpgMK1eOgmw6Y5L-YN2FRZnrk9na5DW0kZEvDiu6b4/edit   
там лог

Comment: NullPointerException, лучше в вопрос добавь код из активити

Comment: Спасибо. После такого чувствую себя совсем дураком...